# NSMutableArray pass-by-reference

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

In my class MyClass1 I have `NSMutableArray` declarated like that:

```
NSMutableArray *somearray = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *somearray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
[somearray addObject: somearray2];
```

Later I create instance of another class and send this array like a parameter:

```
Myclass2 *secondclass = [Myclass2 new];
[secondclass updateData: somearray];
```

In updateData:

```
-(void) updateData:(NSMutableArray *) myArray{
  [myArray[0][1] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"Some text"]; // here receive error
}
```

And Receive error, how I can send link to my "somearray" to another classes and working with him (not a copy them) ? I can create global variable but not won't to do that.

Sorry I update my question.

Error

```
2014-09-09 12:40:38.778 FCalendar[12644:613] -[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]:   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10963fec0
2014-09-09 12:40:38.783 FCalendar[12644:613] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized   selector sent to instance 0x10963fec0'
```

Comment: I'm sure the `myArray` is not a `NSMutableArray` instance, can you log the class of it ? `NSLog(@"%@", [myArray class]);`

Comment: The exception shows it's an `NSArray` not `NSMutableArray`.  The code you post is not accurate.

Comment: Show the stack trace. You are asking for help and hiding the information that is needed. And tell us about any warnings you are getting.

Comment: Sorry I update my question, after I add another NSMA to my first array I cannot work with him.

Answer (score 2):

You have created a `NSArray` instance not a `NSMutableArray`.

Try this :

```
NSMutableArray *somearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];
```

Edit: You correct you question, so I modify my answer.

This line of code is wrong `NSMutableArray *somearray2 = [[NSMutableArray new]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];`, you should use `NSMutableArray *somearray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];` instead.

Then `[myArray[0][1] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"Some text"];`, I think it should be `[myArray[0] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"Some text"];`. Hope it is what you want, long way to go.

Comment: This is mistake, I write manually don't copy from project. I change here, in project everywhere NSMuttableArray.

Comment: @Never_be Not true; the exception message says otherwise.

Comment: I'm sure it's not an NSMuttableArray (can you guess why? ). Copy and paste code, so we don't rely on guesses.

Comment: @gnasher729 :) Changed `NSMuttableArray` to `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Guys everywhere NSMutableArray.

Comment: @Never_be Did you assign something to `somearray` after alloc it ?

Comment: After new I add other Arrays with addObject, I investigate and always when I add mutable array to another mutable array you cannot work with him only first you must make mutable copy, change what you need and replace. myArray[0][1] always get error, only work on first level myArray[0].

Comment: @Never_be `myArray[0][1]` is `NSString` here.